# Midi input on raspberry pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, midi

I have implemented a simple program, that takes input from a Midi keyboard and then outputs the corresponding sound using the javax synthesizer interface.
This works really well on my Pc running Windows, however, I want to run it on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. It actually does work, too, but as soon as i play more/faster notes, the sound starts to jitter and crackle really bad, and i have to stop playing notes for about 2 seconds in order for the jittering to die down.
I am using a external USB sound adapter already, which did not really help alot.
Here is the class that handles the midi input:

```
public class MidiHandler {

    public MidiHandler() {
        MidiDevice device;
        MidiDevice.Info[] infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
            try {
                device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[i]);
                // does the device have any transmitters?
                // if it does, add it to the device list
                System.out.println(infos[i]);

                // get all transmitters
                List<Transmitter> transmitters = device.getTransmitters();
                // and for each transmitter

                for (int j = 0; j < transmitters.size(); j++) {
                    // create a new receiver
                    transmitters.get(j).setReceiver(
                    // using my own MidiInputReceiver
                            new MidiInputReceiver(device.getDeviceInfo()
                                    .toString()));
                }

                Transmitter trans = device.getTransmitter();
                trans.setReceiver(new MidiInputReceiver(device.getDeviceInfo()
                        .toString()));

                // open each device
                device.open();
                // if code gets this far without throwing an exception
                // print a success message
            } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
            }
        }

    }

    // tried to write my own class. I thought the send method handles an
    // MidiEvents sent to it
    public class MidiInputReceiver implements Receiver {
        Synthesizer synth;
        MidiChannel[] mc;
        Instrument[] instr;
        int instrument;
        int channel;



        public MidiInputReceiver(String name) {
            try
            {
                patcher p = new patcher();
                this.instrument = p.getInstrument();
                this.channel = p.getChannel();
                this.synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
                this.synth.open();
                this.mc = synth.getChannels();
                instr = synth.getDefaultSoundbank().getInstruments();
                this.synth.loadInstrument(instr[1]);
                mc[this.channel].programChange(0, this.instrument);
                System.out.println(this.channel + ", " + this.instrument);

            }
            catch (MidiUnavailableException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }

        public void send(MidiMessage msg, long timeStamp) {
            /*
             * Use to display midi message
             * 
            for(int i = 0; i < msg.getMessage().length; i++) {
                System.out.print("[" + msg.getMessage()[i] + "] ");

            }
            System.out.println();
            */
            if (msg.getMessage()[0] == -112) {
                mc[this.channel].noteOn(msg.getMessage()[1], msg.getMessage()[2]+1000);
            }

            if (msg.getMessage()[0] == -128) {
                mc[this.channel].noteOff(msg.getMessage()[1], msg.getMessage()[2]+1000);
            }

        }

        public void close() {
        }
    }
}
```

Is this due to hardware limitations of the Pi, or can I do anything about it?

Comment: What is the CPU utilization?

Comment: @CL while the program is running, the cpu usage is between 30% and 50%. When i play a single note, it goes up to between 60% and 70%. The sound glitches occur whenever the cpu usage reaches above ~90%

Answer (score 0):

If you have any loops for updating the midi retrieval/sound output, maybe try thread-sleeping in there to give the OS time to do stuff? Other than that, not sure. The USB on the original Raspberry Pi wasn't very good for some reason (lots of bugs, slow performance -- but these did get fixed somewhat in newer Linux/firmware). You may also need to modify the sample rate to match the ideal setting for the current sound output, if it's accessible (sample rate mismatch means more conversion). Java may try to use the ideal as the default, but may be misreported by the OS?